# What is prayaschitta for breaking the promise made to Lord Shiva?

Tags: prayaschitta

I broke a promise made to Lord Shiva that I won't mastrubate for a month and I broke and to do prayaschita I again took promise and said him to make me child less if I broke this again but again I broke it now what should I do.

Comment: Read Any Scripture, to control on yourself

Comment: Nature of human mind to break promises as it is attracted towards pleasures.  So your job is not to take vows or oaths like this. Find a way to cross over this. Just like how Sunlight erases darkness within fraction of second, find the route cross to surpass Prakritis functions and attain Lord Shiva and gradually follow one by one in that. Path of light erases automatically darkness in you!